# python to executable size optimization

Tags: python, optimization, pyinstaller, executable

I'm going to build python to executable but the size is big(about 6 MB).
I'd like to reduce size less than 4 MB.

Let me know how to optimize that.
Thanks.

```
from requests import get, post
from sseclient import SSEClient
import time
import subprocess

#set server url
server_uri = 'http://127.0.0.1/server.php'
try:
    my_id = get('https://api.ipify.org').text

    try:
        server = get(server_uri)
        print(server.headers)

        messages = SSEClient(server_uri)
        subprocess.call('ipconfig', shell=True) 

    except Exception as e:
        print("you can't connect to server\n")

except Exception as e:
    print("Please check your internet connection\n")
```

Let me know how to optimize that.

Comment: Where you can, only import the functions you need from modules. Helped me reduce my exe file size a lot, because I was needlessly import full modules

Comment: Please include exactly what you're doing to build your executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using pyinstaller to create executable,  check if you have virtual env. created and only required modules are installed . in some cases all modules are packaged if not dedicated virtual env is created for project .

Comment: Actually, I created virtualenv and worked on there.

Comment: The larges file is python27.dll(3.27MB), _ssl.pyd(2.02MB) and client.exe(1.5MB).

Comment: With this method, the size is at list 5 MB. I require 4MB.

Answer (score 1):

I think to shrink the size of your Python executable

1. Pick a smaller Python distribution: Sometimes, distributions like Anaconda have tons of packages you don't need. If that's the case, try using a smaller distribution like Miniconda and only install the stuff your script actually uses.
2. Use PyInstaller or cx_Freeze: These tools let you make a standalone executable from a Python script that has all the dependencies included. They can even compress the file to make it smaller.
3. Try a different programming language: If you're really desperate to make your executable teeny-tiny, you could think about switching to a different language like Go or Rust that produces smaller executables.